# Pipe character is messing up my pexpect command string

Tags: python, unix, pipe, pexpect

I have a string that I build then pass to pexpect:

```
command = "for i in `python /tmp/"+ cecUser + "_getSyslogs.py " + startString + " " + endString + " " + myDir + "`;do gzcat /emslogs/archive/" + myDir + "/$i | grep " + node + " | egrep -v \"" + filteredWords + "\" >> /tmp/" + syslogFile + ";done"

p.sendline(command)
```

If `filteredWords` = "No LMA address", the script runs fine.

If `filteredWords` = "No LMA address|CLISess", the script fails.

What am I missing? I tried to escape the `|` by preceding with `\` and that didn't help. I actually tried a whole slew of different combinations and the script still fails. What is even odder is the logging output from p.logfile looks fine:

```
$ for i in `python /tmp/getSyslogs.py 20141227120000 20141228120000 local1`;do gzcat /emslogs/archive/local1/$i | grep ALPRGAGQPN2 | egrep -v "No LMA address|CLISess" >> /tmp/1419900585.83_ALPRGAGQPN2_syslogs.txt;done
```

If I cut'n'paste that line on the target machine, it works no problem. There is just something about the pipe in the egrep that is messing up when passed to p.sendline.

Comment: have tried using .format() instead of many concatenations?

Comment: If you use `"` then you need double escaping of the pipe. To escape the backslash from bash to have a backslash in the pattern. `"...\\|..."`

Comment: Thanks for your responses and for taking the time to format my post. I formatted the string using Xr's advice. Much more readable. But adding the "...\\|..." still didn't help. I'll continue trying different combinations to escape the pipe.

Comment: For what it's worth, the only way I managed to get around the "|" issue in the egrep command is to write the command to a file then execute the file using the shell. There is something very strange going on with the parsing and I'm not convinced it's not a bug. Thank you all for your help.